# check input value between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Below is my database schema.

```
id   from  to    value
1    1     10    5
2    11    NULL  10   -- I have stored 'NULL' for any value GREATER THAN 11
```

Now i have to select `value` where `input like (4)` is between `from` and `to`.

I know that it can be achieved with this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  4 BETWEEN `from` AND `to`
```

But how to select value where `input` is like `15`?

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  15 BETWEEN `from` AND `to`
```

In this case above query will not work because `to` column has `null`.

**UPDATE**

columen `to` will contain `null` if it can have any value.

Now If input value is `15`, then query should return 2nd row, because `15 is not between 1 and 10 in 1st row` and `15` is greater than 11 and `to` value can be anything greater than 11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  15 BETWEEN coalesce(`from`,15) AND coalesce(`to`,15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean combinations

```
select *
    from table
    where (to is not null and 15 between from and to)
        or (to is null and 15 >= from)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  15 BETWEEN `from` AND IF_NULL(`to`,15)
```